# PHP runs out of memory if gc_collect_cycles() is not called

Tags: php, garbage-collection

I just experienced PHP 8.2 running out of memory, however, if I add `gc_collect_cycles()` it wont. Is that a bug? Shouldn't PHP try to run the garbage collector before raising the out-of-memory fatal error?

Here a minimal code snippet that shows the issue (run with `php -d memory_limit=200M script.php`):

```
<?php

class Foo {
    private $bar; // Cyclic references between Foo and Bar instances.

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = new Bar($this);
    }
}

class Bar {
    private $foo; // Cyclic references between Foo and Bar instances.
    private $longStr;

    public function __construct($foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;

        // Allocate a 30MB string.
        $this->longStr =  sprintf("%30000000s", "");
    }
}

function doLoop($forceGc) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
        $foo = new Foo();

        if ($forceGc) {
            gc_collect_cycles();
        }
    }
}

doLoop(true); // This works fine.
doLoop(false); // This throws "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 209715200 bytes exhausted".
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, garbage collection is generally a relatively expensive operation, so PHP isn't continuously running it. According to [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php), it kicks in once 10,000 objects are in the "root buffer".

Comment: Sure, I understand that. My question is whether it might also be the right time before forcing the program down?
I'm also wondering why the root buffer has a fixed size as this doesn't account for the objects' sizes.

Comment: So, "why doesn't PHP try to perform a garbage collection before throwing a fatal memory error"? My guess is that it would have to run the code, realize it is out of memory, GC, and then try re-running the code which could lead to unexpected results.